# Customize OpenWhisk Invoker to use microkernel

Tags: openwhisk, microkernel

I am trying to customize OpenWhisk to call a microkernel from the Invoker, rather than Docker.  Is there an effort underway currently to add this support, or a development guide covering the changes I would need to make?  My current understanding of the code is that this will be a substantial project.

EDIT: To ask the question more pointedly, is there guidance available on how to move away from the concept of containers?  Or will I be better off treating a microkernel as an abstracted type of container?

Answer (score 1):

Given OpenWhisk is an Apache project, I believe this question is a perfect fit for the relevant mailing-list. You'll find all the contributors there and it is much more geared for a discussion (which is needed for this topic I think).

Please refer to http://openwhisk.incubator.apache.org/contact.html for more information on how to reach the dev-list.

Answer (score 0):

This PR that integrated Mesos into OpenWhisk may give you an idea of the required changes: https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/pull/2833